# GZip uncompress component issue

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am working on mule flow and running into difficulties

**Requirement:**

1. Get the ZIP file from Payload
2. Unzip it and get the list of file names
3. Zip it back
4. FTP the same

I am running into 2 issues

1. Get the original FileName - I tried different combinations like #[message.inboundProperties.originalFileName] but getting null value.
2. Unzip file

**Below is my flow**(I have not included FTP and ZIP flow as running into issues before FTP)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a tad confused by your requirements as described, the use of GZip compression, and you're flow screenshot.

Your requirement suggests you're going to be loading a Zip archive (file), which is very different to a GZip stream - the GZip connector won't help you here. GZip simply compresses a stream of bytes, it doesn't have the concept of multiple files/folders within it - this is why in the *nix world it's usually combined with Tar (i.e. Tar joins together many files into a single, uncompressed archive and that archive is then GZip'd). Zip essentially combines both of these - archive and compress.

Also, your screenshot shows a HTTP inbound endpoint - so I assume the file is being posted to you. `#[message.inboundProperties.originalFileName]` is only set by a File inbound endpoint, which is why you won't be seeing it. You also don't mention what content type you'll be working with. The most common use case I've seen is `multipart/form-data` - and if you're using that then you can access the file and it's name via Mule's `inboundAttachments` map.

If my understanding of what you're doing is correct, the following is an example of how I would implement it (error checking/handling removed for brevity):

[image: Sample flow]

Source:

```
    <flow name="sampleFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/zip" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <foreach collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" doc:name="For Each Attachment (There could be more than 1)">
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy - examine attachment and set vars">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

// should be application/zip - could valudate
flowVars.type = payload.dataSource.contentType;

// datasource will be HttpPartDataSource
flowVars.partName = payload.dataSource.part.name;
flowVars.filename = payload.dataSource.part.fileName;
flowVars.filesInZip = new java.util.ArrayList();

payload = payload.dataSource.content;

ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload));
ZipEntry ze;
while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
    flowVars.filesInZip.add(ze.name);
zis.close();

return payload;

]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="21" path="/dest" passive="true" outputPattern="#[flowVars.filename]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-session-variable variableName="results"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
(sessionVars.results default []) ++ [{
    partName: flowVars.partName,
    fileName: flowVars.filename,
    filesInZip: flowVars.filesInZip joinBy ', '
}]
]]></dw:set-session-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </foreach>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
sessionVars.results
]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
</flow>
```

Postman Sample Call:

[image: Postman Sample]

Output:

```
[
    {
        "partName": "zip2",
        "fileName": "OC.zip",
        "filesInZip": "OC/staging/, OC/staging/b2b-test/, OC/staging/Madrid/, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805259-1527220273.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805259-1527221226.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805259-1527226248.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805259-1527226249.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805259-1527226475.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805259-1527226476.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805299-1527544507.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805299-1527545678.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805299-1527545679.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805299-1527548307.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805299-1527550180.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805299-1527553547.txt, OC/staging/Madrid/B1805299-1527553548.txt"
    },
    {
        "partName": "zip1",
        "fileName": "FirstZipFile.zip",
        "filesInZip": "LogitechWebcamFix.log, BGChanger.log"
    }
]
```